# Support for custom MapView/Android-View in Visual Studio

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio-2013, android-view

I am translating code from Java to C# with the original Java version in [this walkthrough](http://ghoscher.me/2012/04/06/mapapp5-mapview-and-activity/) and I noticed that when translating there is a major problem and that is the custom MapView:

```
public MapView(Context context, int viewWidth, int viewHeight, DataClass tilesProvider, Bitmap positionmarker)
        {
            //super(context);

            //base.Context(context);
            //base is the equivalent to the unexplained use of super

            this.context = context;

            this.tileProvider = tilesProvider;

            this.viewHeight = viewHeight;
            this.viewWidth = viewWidth;

            this.positionmarker = positionmarker;

            tileManager = new TilesManager(256, viewWidth, viewHeight);

            initPaint();

            fetchTiles();



        }
```

I get the error: "Android.Views.View does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments."

If I make it static `this` will not work and there is no MapView in the View baseclass.

How can I make it work or is that impossible?
If impossible is there an optional way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am unable to build and that might create later problems but here is my solution that I found:

```
public MapView(Context context, int viewWidth, int viewHeight, DataClass tilesProvider, Bitmap positionMarker): base(context)
    {
        //base(context);
        //super(context);


        //base.Context(context);
        //base unexplained use of super that 

        this.context = context;

        this.tileProvider = tilesProvider;

        this.viewHeight = viewHeight;
        this.viewWidth = viewWidth;

        this.positionmarker = positionMarker;

        tileManager = new TilesManager(256, viewWidth, viewHeight);

        initPaint();

        fetchTiles();


        //return base.(context, viewWidth, viewHeight, tilesProvider, tilesManager);

    }
```

The solution was to put `: base(context)` in the method declaration and not inside the method that was done in the Java version. I found the explanation on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms836794.aspx).

Now with the hope that this works later on to, hope this is of any use to other people! /E.A.O.S